# Values are auto populating in Hive database box in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am using Hive in my Flutter app, and in most spots, it works as desired. However, I've noticed that when saving values in one section, I have an issue when restarting the app after I've closed it from Android Studio.

Here's the situation:

In my main file:

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
var boxSelected = await Hive.openBox('selectedBox');
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Then, in another page in my app I add and remove to that box using **put(key, value)** and **delete(key)**. This actually all works **while my app is running**. And just FYI, I am importing  Hive in that page file and referencing the same box.

However, let's say over the course of my app session I've added 5 objects (just regular map key/value items), and then deleted 3 of them, I would expect that after I restart the app I would only have 2 items left (like how I left it). **That's not the case.**

What's happening is when I restart the app, it's auto populating the db with all 5 items.

I'd really like to know why this is happening, and also, how to fix it.

Like I said, I implement multiple Hive boxes in my app, and they all work fine.

Thanks for any help. Let me know if you need more info.